# jQuery detect when scroll is within and not past a certain div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following divs

```
<div id="item-1" >item 1 content get here </div>
<div id="item-2" >item 2 content get here </div>
```

I would like to execute a function when the scroll is between the div content and when the scroll goes beyond the div then execute a different function.

In my jQuery I have

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
            var divs = ["item-1","item-2"]; //the above two divs

            divs.forEach(function(item){
                var current_div =  $('#'+item).offset().top
                if(current_div <  window.pageYOffset) {
                    console.log("I have reached the div", item);
                }
            });
            
        });
```

The above works when scrolling to the bottom, but doesn't work when scrolling to top. It also doesn't detect when I scroll beyond a certain div.

How can I detect when scroll is only with a certain div? The divs are dynamic, hence the need to use the array.

Comment: i test it on a snippet and work (jquey slim)

Comment: the above works when scrolling from top to bottom but doesnt work when i scroll beyond the div. That is i want it to console.log once the scroll is within the div and when scrolled beyond the div it shouldnt.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should work with the code below.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256 QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var divs = ["item-1","item-2"]; //the above two divs

        divs.forEach(function(item){
            var current_div =  $('#'+item).offset().top
            if(current_div <  window.pageYOffset) {
                console.log("I have reached the div", item);
            }
        });

    });
```

And then your HTML

```
<div id="item-1" >item 1 content get here </div>
<div id="item-2" >item 2 content get here </div>
```

Note: The only change made is the JQuery inclusion.

Enjoy!

Comment: when i scroll beyond item-1 it still continues console.log. I want the console.log to work only when  the scroll is within the div.